# various div contained in parent div and responsive to parent size

Tags: html, css, alignment, responsive

I would like to have all the div(1..7) inside the parent div next to each other and that when the size of the screen changes (portrait,landscape, scale) the organization of the div1..7 is done automatically so that they are always contained in the parent div.

So far I succeeded in:

- have a centered parent which is responsive to any screen situation
- all the div1..7 inside the parent div (but they are on top of each other)

What I miss:

- div1..7 next to each other
- div1..7 re-organized/resized automatically when the size of parent div change due to screen change.

```css
html {background: #eee;}
* {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
html, body {height: 100%;text-align: center;}
.container{display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: 10vh; background: rgba(200,200,200,0.5);}
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {.container {width: 60vw; height: 80vh;}}
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {.container {width: 80vw; height: 80vh;}}

.div1 {display: block; background: rgba(80,0,0,0.5); width:100px; height:100px;float:left;}
.div2 {display: block; background: rgba(0,80,0,0.5); width:200px; height:100px;float:left;}
.div3 {display: block; background: rgba(0,0,80,0.5); width:100px; height:200px;float:left;}
.div4 {display: block; background: rgba(80,0,0,0.5); width:100px; height:100px;float:left;}
.div5 {display: block; background: rgba(0,80,0,0.5); width:200px; height:100px;float:left;}
.div6 {display: block; background: rgba(0,0,80,0.5); width:100px; height:200px;float:left;}
.div7 {display: block; background: rgba(80,0,0,0.5); width:100px; height:100px;float:left;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="div1"></div>
 <div class="div2"></div>
 <div class="div3"></div>
 <div class="div4"></div>
 <div class="div5"></div>
 <div class="div6"></div>
 <div class="div7"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're doing a mistake in the code snippet: you've forgotten to close the `div` tags using `</div>`... I'll modify it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure of what you really expect at the end .

- fixed width and height using the window's size might come too small at one point.
- boxes of different heights and widths can wrap onto few lines but won't imbricate

To center x,y the container , you may use the display table or flex properties. and avoid margins.It will allow also scrolling if the window comes too small.

here is a examples , do not hesitate to clarify :)

table display

```css
.div6,
.div3 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 80, 0.5);
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

.div2,
.div5 {
  background: rgba(0, 80, 0, 0.5);
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.div7,
.div1,
.div4 {
  background: rgba(80, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container>div {
  float: left;
  /*see me */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eee;
}

body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.container {
  display:inline-block;
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
  .container {
    max-width: 60vw;
  }
}

@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
  .container {
    max-width: 80vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
  <div class="div4"></div>
  <div class="div5"></div>
  <div class="div6"></div>
  <div class="div7"></div>
</div>
```

flex display

```css
.div6,
.div3 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 80, 0.5);
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

.div2,
.div5 {
  background: rgba(0, 80, 0, 0.5);
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.div7,
.div1,
.div4 {
  background: rgba(80, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container>div {
  float: left;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: #eee;
}

body {
  margin:auto;
  display:flex;/* .container will wrap float elements and will show bg */
}
.container {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
  .container {
    max-width: 60vw;
  }
}

@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
  .container {
    max-width: 80vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
  <div class="div4"></div>
  <div class="div5"></div>
  <div class="div6"></div>
  <div class="div7"></div>
</div>
```

---

`display:grid` will alow divs to imbricate / span through columns or rows.

*it also centers easily x,y a single element*:

example with static sizes:

```css
.div6,
.div3 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 80, 0.5);
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.div2,
.div5 {
  background: rgba(0, 80, 0, 0.5);
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.div7,
.div1,
.div4 {
  background: rgba(80, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container>div {
  margin: auto;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  background: #eee;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  /* to center x,y */
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,100px);
  grid-gap: 1vh;
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
  .container {
    width: 60vw;
    height: 80vh;
  }
}

@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
  .container {
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
  <div class="div4"></div>
  <div class="div5"></div>
  <div class="div6"></div>
  <div class="div7"></div>
</div>
```

unlucky example resizing

```css
.div6,
.div3 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 80, 0.5);
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  max-height:36vh;
  max-width:18vh;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.div2,
.div5 {
  background: rgba(0, 80, 0, 0.5);
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  max-height:18vh;
  max-width:36vh;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.div7,
.div1,
.div4 {
  background: rgba(80, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  max-height:18vh;
  max-width:18vh;
}

.container>div {
  margin: auto;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  background: #eee;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  /* to center x,y */
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(10vh, 20vh));
  grid-gap: 1vh;
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
  .container {
    width: 60vw;
    height: 80vh;
  }
}

@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
  .container {
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
  <div class="div4"></div>
  <div class="div5"></div>
  <div class="div6"></div>
  <div class="div7"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. We are getting closer... Well at the end, this is what I want to do (see picture here: https://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large/various-wooden-photo-frames-hang-on-a-wall-aleksandr-volkov.jpg ) The goal is to have divs (framed pictures) inside a container (wall) and that this view adapt if the wall size move. Of course maintaining width/height is mandatory so pictures aren't deformed and anyway it is not to display it too small. Just to adapt to any screen resolution. And of course in portrait, the organization of pictures would adapt too.

Comment: @yoan26 okay, see the last snippet using grid . , you can reset grid-gap so elements won't touch each others display grid has been lately implemented in most of newest browsers , ie10 remains a trouble using an older syntax

Comment: ok indeed this is good. Just one last request then. At the moment when the screen becomes really small, then the grey div get out of the screen and I have to scroll to see all. Any chance to avoid this by not only re-organization thanks to flex but also reduce size of divs (while keeping there ratio) ?

Comment: @yoan26 yes, then use also vh and vw units via max-width/max-height . i'll update the snippet

Comment: still some strange behavior but I should be able to work on it myself from the snippet you made. I will close the question. Thanks again all for feedbacks.

Answer (score 0):

the div close tag is missing...

and you can use flexbox in order to put your divbs next to each other

```css
html {background: #eee;}
* {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
html, body {height: 100%;text-align: center;}
.container{display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: 10vh; background: rgba(200,200,200,0.5);
display:flex;}
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {.container {width: 60vw; height: 80vh;}}
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {.container {width: 80vw; height: 80vh;}}

.div1 {display: block; background: rgba(80,0,0,0.5); width:100px; height:100px;float:left;}
.div2 {display: block; background: rgba(0,80,0,0.5); width:200px; height:100px;float:left;}
.div3 {display: block; background: rgba(0,0,80,0.5); width:100px; height:200px;float:left;}
.div4 {display: block; background: rgba(80,0,0,0.5); width:100px; height:100px;float:left;}
.div5 {display: block; background: rgba(0,80,0,0.5); width:200px; height:100px;float:left;}
.div6 {display: block; background: rgba(0,0,80,0.5); width:100px; height:200px;float:left;}
.div7 {display: block; background: rgba(80,0,0,0.5); width:100px; height:100px;float:left;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="div1"></div>
 <div class="div2"></div>
 <div class="div3"></div>
 <div class="div4"></div>
 <div class="div5"></div>
 <div class="div6"></div>
 <div class="div7"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, indeed... forgot the /div. The problem is that with this now if the parent grey get smaller than total width of all divs, then their width reduces as seen when running the snippet. What I would like is that if 7divs can't fit in the first row anymore, then they are moved to a second row etc etc. Not sure if it's clear. I will continue to work on that.

Comment: In other terms, if I change the size of my window, no matter how the grey adapt its size, I would like the divs inside to 1.keep the same ratio size 2. shrink or go to next line so that they stay in the grey box.